# Ошибка  Table 'paramon.pirog' doesn't exist

Tags: php

Что тут не так выскакивает ошибка Table 'paramon.pirog' doesn't exist Код:

```
<?php
include ("db.php");
$query2="SELECT * FROM `pirog`  LIMIT 5";
 $res2 = mysql_query($query2) or die(mysql_error());
 if(mysql_num_rows($res2)>0){
   while($show2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2)){
    printf("
     <div >%s</div>
       <div >%s</div>
    ",$show2['id'],$show2['vo']);
   }
  }
  else{
  echo '<div style="text-align:center;">Пока ни кто не пробил урон</div>';
  }
  ?>
```

Comment: @Vlmake, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

----------

P.S. Table 'paramon.pirog' doesn't exist - переводиться с непонятного языка, как "**Таблица 'paramon.pirog' не существует**".

Comment: Я знаю как это переводится НО ОНА СУЩЕСТВУЕТ

Comment: @Vlmake, Проверьте, что без ошибок пишите название таблицы. А то мало ли... слово "никто", вы же абсолютно случайно, но написали раздельно ;)


И вообще, "чилавеку свойствина ашыбаца" ))

Comment: Я вот так "ЧИЛАВЕКУ СВОЙСТВИНА АШЫБАЦА" не пишу

Comment: делаем ставки - не к тому серверу подключаемся... база например на внешнем сервере. а в конфиге localhost

Comment: @eicto, поддерживаю.

Answer (score 3):

И так, начнем с того, что товарищ **[@Deonis](/users/4058/deonis)**, правильно подметил, цитирую:

> Table 'paramon.pirog' doesn't exist - переводиться с непонятного языка, как "Таблица 'paramon.pirog' не существует".

Значит, нам нужно открыть нашу **phpmyadmin**, другими словами **MySQL**, удостовериться, что такой таблицы не существует и создать ее, после чего проблема исчезнет.

Comment: она существует

Comment: @Vlmake, а она в той БД?

Answer (score 3):

[@Vlmake](/users/10191/vlmake), если написано **Table 'paramon.pirog' doesn't exist** значит она и правда **doesn't exist**. Вы бы лучше не пытались доказать нам в каждом вашем предложении, что она есть, а попытались найти ошибку.

А ошибки могут быть везде. Например:

1. в названии базы данных а не таблицы
2. возможно затесалась кириллица в названии БД/Таблицы. (вместо "p"(пэ) "p"(эр) или типа того)

Перепроверите еще раз. И вообще перепроверяйте до тех пор пока не найдете ошибку. Потому что нет той таблицы, к которой вы пытаетесь обратиться. По крайней мере нет той таблицы, что вы написали в запросе.